Optimized bubble sorting algorithm takes more time than unoptimzed
I can't understand why do optimized version of my bubble sorting algorithm takes not less time than unoptimized version
Here is my files:
main.c - here I create arrays of different sizes and run both of algorithms
#define RAND_NUM rand() % 1000;

int main(void) {
    srand(time(nullptr));

    constexpr int arrays_sizes[] = {10'000, 50'000, 100'000};
    constexpr int arrays_sizes_size = sizeof(arrays_sizes) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays_sizes_size; ++i) {
        const int array_size = arrays_sizes[i];
        int *nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);
        int *nums_copy = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);

        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
            nums[i] = RAND_NUM;
        }

        copy_arr(nums_copy, nums, array_size);
        clock_t begin = clock();
        BUBBLE_SORT_RETURN_TYPE steps_count = bubble_sort(nums_copy, array_size);
        clock_t end = clock();

        long int time_spent = end - begin;

        printf("Bubble sort on array size of %d: Time: %ldms | Approximate steps count: %lu\n", array_size, time_spent, steps_count);

        copy_arr(nums_copy, nums, array_size);
        begin = clock();
        steps_count = bubble_sort_2(nums_copy, array_size);
        end = clock();

        time_spent = end - begin;

        printf("Bubble sort V2 on array size of %d: Time: %ldms | Approximate steps count: %lu\n", array_size, time_spent, steps_count);

        free(nums);
        free(nums_copy);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bubble_sort.c - unoptimized version
BUBBLE_SORT_RETURN_TYPE bubble_sort(int *arr, const size_t size) {
    BUBBLE_SORT_RETURN_TYPE steps_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j) {

            ++steps_count;

            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                swap(arr, j, j + 1);
                ++steps_count;
            }
        }
    }

    return steps_count;
}

bubble_sort_2.c - optimized version
BUBBLE_SORT_RETURN_TYPE bubble_sort_2(int *arr, const size_t size) {
    BUBBLE_SORT_RETURN_TYPE steps_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        bool is_sorted = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j) {

            ++steps_count;

            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                is_sorted = false;
                swap(arr, j, j + 1);
                ++steps_count;
            }
        }

        if (is_sorted) break;
    }

    return steps_count;
}

swap.c
void swap(int *nums, const int i, const int j) {
    const int temp = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = temp;
}

copy_arr.c
void copy_arr(int *into, const int *from, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        into[i] = from[i];
    }
}

#define BUBBLE_SORT_RETURN_TYPE unsigned long int
Here is the output which I get:
Bubble sort on array size of 10000: Time: 104ms | Approximate steps count: 74933780
Bubble sort V2 on array size of 10000: Time: 109ms | Approximate steps count: 74917127
Bubble sort on array size of 50000: Time: 2714ms | Approximate steps count: 1872216503
Bubble sort V2 on array size of 50000: Time: 2801ms | Approximate steps count: 1872215278
Bubble sort on array size of 100000: Time: 11628ms | Approximate steps count: 3203308155
Bubble sort V2 on array size of 100000: Time: 12672ms | Approximate steps count: 3203284719

As you can see the steps count in V2 less than in unoptimzied version but it takes more time. Why?
May be here is an syntax misunderstanding of how to measure the time?
UPD
I added -O3 in CMakeLists.txt (what is interesting is that now without this option tests take 2 times more time):

and running each version separately (simply comment lines of another) now output is this:
Bubble sort on array size of 10000: Time: 106ms | Approximate steps count: 75067454
Bubble sort on array size of 50000: Time: 2502ms | Approximate steps count: 1871055432
Bubble sort on array size of 100000: Time: 10572ms | Approximate steps count: 3204464485

Bubble sort V2 on array size of 10000: Time: 112ms | Approximate steps count: 74832502
Bubble sort V2 on array size of 50000: Time: 2788ms | Approximate steps count: 1873409635
Bubble sort V2 on array size of 100000: Time: 12325ms | Approximate steps count: 3201737439

So the nothing is really changed...

Are you building with optimizations?  Did you profile your optimized version to see if you're just getting nailed by missed branch prediction on if(is_sorted)?

@StephenNewell I just click "Run" in my CLion editor. And what does mean "missed branch"? In outputs I saw the less steps count doesn't that mean that I'm not missing anything?

Is there any reason to have those extra functions in other source files? That'll prevents the compiler being able to optimize your code as effectively.

I don't use clion, so you'll need to figure out what compilation flags it's using.  And the term is "missed branch prediction" not "missing branch."  Branch prediction can make a huge difference in how code performs.

Discussing performance when optimizations are disabled is pointless. Any version of your code can take any arbitrary time when optimizations are off.

While the change in V2 is technically an optimization in terms of the number of iterations, this is still bubble sort on a large array of randomly-sorted values. You're likely to have some value near one end that needs to slowly make its way to the other end. An early exit won't save you all that much time. On my machine, with optimizations enabled, I get a very small reduction in runtime for the V2 version (with all the functions in a single source file, and the helpers being static inline).

Also, running both benchmarks from the same process is questionable. There's all manner of subtle crap like "cold/hot cache" or how/when the OS decides to actually do dynamic allocation - it doesn't necessarily happen at the time when you call malloc. Getting benchmarking right it very difficult. Around 95% of all performance questions on SO can be explained with incorrect benchmarkning methods. I'm not exaggerating.

constexpr is not C at all

@phuclv "constexpr is not C at all" - guess what C23 did?

@JohnBayko it would not surprise me if most C compilers are based on C++ compilers, so the compilers probably had it long before the spec did.

As an aside, do not srand(time(nullptr)) in a benchmark.  This makes your program non-deterministic, so you can't reliably compare its results.

The tiny 0.0007% reduction in the number of steps is likely swamped by the increase in the number of instructions in each iteration for setting and testing is_sorted.
You are likely to get different and more significant results by applying compiler optimisation to either version.
Optimising a notoriously sub-optimal algorithm however probably has little merit.

The only time the "optimized" version should be significantly faster is if the input is nearly sorted already.

@MarkRansom agreed.  I don't think I suggested otherwise.

No, you did not suggest otherwise.  But you left it unsaid.  I thought it was worth pointing out.  P.S. everything you did say has my approval.

@MarkRansom - if the data is nearly sorted, but the smallest element is at the end, then the is_sorted flag is just overhead and won't provide an early out. In general it's the smallest elements that only get shifted left one on each pass that determines the number of passes.

Use a more accurate timing function such as clock_gettime() in C instead of clock() for more precise timing, especially on smaller datasets. I had a similar issue with clock().
Also, use a profiler (e.g., gprof, perf, or valgrind) to check where most of the time is being spent. This can reveal if there are specific hotspots like excessive branching or cache misses in the optimized version, tho you will see that is_sorted() is adding that tiny increment in time.
Furthermore, have you tired to compile with different optimization levels (e.g., -O2, -O3) and see if the behavior changes?
Try these and give us a feedback.

Note: clock_gettime() is not part of the standard C library.  clock() and int timespec_get(struct timespec *ts, int base) are part of the standard C library.

Even if all of the data is sorted except for the smallest element being at the end, then the is_sorted flag is just overhead and won't provide an early out. In general it's the smallest elements that only get shifted left one on each pass that determines the number of passes. A shaker sort that passes both ways could help a little, but both are still O(n^2) algorithms.
